# Does RMSProp optimizer in tensorflow use Nesterov momentum?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

When you create RMSPRop optimizer, it asks for the momentum value. What is this momentum? Is it Nesterov or the other one? How do I use Nesterov momentum with the RMSProp in tf?

There is a formula in the doc string here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/rmsprop.py#L25

```
mean_square = decay * mean_square{t-1} + (1-decay) * gradient ** 2
mom = momentum * mom{t-1} + learning_rate * g_t / sqrt(mean_square + epsilon)
delta = - mom
```

Could someone explain what's the g_t term mean and where is this formula being computed?

As far as I understand, in Nesterov momentum+rmsprop you first change the weights with the current momentum, compute new gradients, divide them by the sqrt(mean_square+epsilon) and add to the momentum. Is this what's happening here? I wasn't able to find the implementation of training_ops.apply_rms_prop since I'm not very familiar with the tf source.

I'm coming from coursera Geoffrey Hinton course about neural networks, where this Nesterov momentum+rmsprop algorithm is explained. How do I use it in tf?

Please, correct me if I'm wrong in my understanding of Nesterov momentum or any other thing.

Comment: `g_t` and `gradient` here are precisely the same thing. This thing is a derivative of your cost function with regard to your parameters.

Comment: @xolodec Thanks! Do you know a place where it all(formula from the doc string) being calculated? Maybe then I will learn if it's a Nesterov momentum or not

Comment: [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2c8d0dca978a246f54c506aae4587dbce5d3bcf0/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L269-L272) could be the place you are asking about.

Comment: @xolodec wohoo. yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. The documentation you refer to explicitly mentions:

   > This implementation of RMSProp uses plain momentum, not Nesterov momentum.
2. AFAIK there is no built-in implementation for Nesterov momentum in RMSProp. You can of course adjust the function according to your own needs.
3. As @xolodec said, `g_t` is the gradient.